# How can I have a single server accepting secure traffic for 2 differents web sites

Tags: java, ssl

Using "let's encrypt", I have created certificates for my 2 web sites.
I have used certbot / openssl / keytool to finally end up with: site1.keystore and site2.keystore

Here is my simplified java code:

```
public class TestServer
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    int port = 1443;
    char[] passphrase = "changeit".toCharArray();
    
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    ks.load(new FileInputStream ("/path/to/site1.keystore"), passphrase);

    KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
    kmf.init(ks, passphrase);

    SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    ctx.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), null, null);

    SSLServerSocketFactory ssf = null;
    ssf = ctx.getServerSocketFactory();

    ServerSocket ss = ssf.createServerSocket(port);
    while (true)
    {
      Socket socket = ss.accept();
      OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
      String response = "Hello from secure server";
      out.write(("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\nContent-Length: " + response.length() + "\r\n\r\n" + response).getBytes());
      out.flush();
      socket.close();
    }
  }
}
```

If I use site1.keystore , I can connect to site1
If I use site2.keystore , I can connect to site2
So far so good...

To be able to connect to both sites, I have merged both keystore in a single all.keystore

Unfortunately it does not work as expected ... maybe somebody has an idea of what is missing?

Comment: You basically need to use the correct keystore based on the `Host` header. If someone requests site1.com you need to use site1.keystore and site2.keystore for site2.com. How are you currently communicating with your server? What domains are the SSL certificates for?

Comment: I can only read the host header AFTER connection has occurred.

Comment: Ah, absolutely correct, my bad. Then https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication is what you need. (or different ports or different IPs)

Answer (score 1):

After digging the "Server Name Indication" (thanks luk2302) I have found 2 possible solutions to my problem.
The easiest one is to have a single certificate for my 2 sites; this can be achieved with:

```
sudo certbot certonly --force-renewal --standalone -d site1.com -d site2.com ...
```

And then build my keystore as usual.

If I still want to have a single certificate per site, the solution is more complex: accept any socket connection, read and analyse the TLS header , grab the server name destination and then we know which is the needed certificate.

There is a good technote on the subject:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#SNIExamples